# Can Tornado communicate with Cassandra, in Non-blocking asynchronous style?

Tags: asynchronous, cassandra, thrift, tornado, nonblocking

I'm working on a web project, which have to process so many client
requests. So I am considering to use Cassandra and tornado. Tornado
seems to have a build-in client(tornado.httpclient.AsyncHTTPClient),
which can do http Non-Blocking request. But, Cassandra uses Thrift protocol. Using Thrift, Tornado seems to be blocked while quering to Cassandra.

Has anyone got expereince? Please suggest how should I do.
Or, is there any add-on module for this purpose?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a Twisted Cassandra client at http://github.com/driftx/Telephus.  I imagine you'd need to write something like that for Tornado.  (Switching to Twisted might be easier. :)

Comment: Telephus may be one reference code.
(But I have never used Twisted framework. Learning Twisted may take some time.)
Thanks.

Comment: If you want to stick with the Tornado interface, you could use Telephus with Cyclone, a Twisted port of Tornado: https://github.com/fiorix/cyclone